# Error in setExceptionListener in sending message via JmsTemplate to ActivemQ (as external broker of Jboss-eap)

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jboss-eap-6

Based on [this article](http://rastkososkic.blogspot.de/2013/12/deploying-activemq-590-resource-adapter.html), I've connected `Jboss eap 6.2` to an external `ActivemQ 5.9.0`. For sending/receiving message i'm using `JmsTemplate` and `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` in `spring-jms 4.1.1`. Receiving message is working fine, but in sending message i get this error:

```
11:33:37,059 ERROR [stderr]  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11:33:37,060 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:33:37,060 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
11:33:37,060 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:33:37,061 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
11:33:37,061 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
11:33:37,061 ERROR [stderr]     at core.util.timer.MethodInvocationScheduledJob.run(MethodInvocationScheduledJob.java:19)
11:33:37,061 ERROR [stderr]     at core.util.timer.JobScheduler$ScheduledJobThread.run(JobScheduler.java:132)
11:33:37,062 ERROR [stderr]  Caused by: org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: setExceptionListener call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'exceptionListener' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead. Alternatively, activate SingleConnectionFactory's 'reconnectOnException' feature, which will allow for registering further ExceptionListeners to the recovery chain.; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: setExceptionListener call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'exceptionListener' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead. Alternatively, activate SingleConnectionFactory's 'reconnectOnException' feature, which will allow for registering further ExceptionListeners to the recovery chain.
11:33:37,062 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279)
11:33:37,062 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
11:33:37,063 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
11:33:37,063 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:59)
11:33:37,063 ERROR [stderr]     at core.security.jms.SecurityMessageSender.sendSecuritySetting(SecurityMessageSender.java:19)
11:33:37,064 ERROR [stderr]     at core.security.synchronizer.SecuritySynchronizer.synchronize(SecuritySynchronizer.java:34)
11:33:37,064 ERROR [stderr]     ... 7 more
11:33:37,064 ERROR [stderr]  Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: setExceptionListener call not supported on proxy for shared Connection. Set the 'exceptionListener' property on the SingleConnectionFactory instead. Alternatively, activate SingleConnectionFactory's 'reconnectOnException' feature, which will allow for registering further ExceptionListeners to the recovery chain.
11:33:37,065 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:504)
11:33:37,065 ERROR [stderr]     at $Proxy147.setExceptionListener(Unknown Source)
11:33:37,065 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.prepareConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:364)
11:33:37,065 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:289)
11:33:37,065 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:225)
11:33:37,066 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
11:33:37,066 ERROR [stderr]     at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:456)
11:33:37,066 ERROR [stderr]     ... 11 more
```

Here is my spring/jms configurations (`reconnectOnException` property of `SingleConnectionFactory` and `CachingConnectionFactory` is activated):

```
<bean name="defaultJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="abstractMessageListenerContainer" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="singleConncetionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="1" />
    <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="5" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" />
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="7000" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="singleConncetionFactory" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="singleConncetionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="${jms.connectionfactory.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jms.connectionfactory.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.connectionfactory.jndi}" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And Jboss `resource-adapter` for ActivemQ (in `standalone.xml`):

```
<resource-adapter id="activemq-rar.ra">
    <module slot="main" id="org.apache.activemq"/>
    <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
    <config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616</config-property>
    <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/activemq/ConnectionFactory"enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQConnectionFactoryPool">
        </connection-definition>
    </connection-definitions>
</resource-adapter>
```

**UPDATE:**

When i inject `singleConnectionFactory` instead of `cachingConnectionFactory` in my `defaultJmsTemplate` bean, the error disappears!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cachingConnectionFactory`'s `targetConnectionFactory` should not be another `SingleConnectionFactory` (it's already one because it's a subclass).

Instead, set the `cachingConnectionFactory`'s `targetConnectionFactory` to `userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter`.

Comment: Why? I haven't this problem in other brokers, like hornetq.

Comment: I didn't dig into as to why/whether this is the cause of your problem; your configuration just jumped out to me as odd; the `SingleConnectionFactory` is redundant; the `CachingConnectionFactory` already maintains a single connection. Plus, your 'update' indicating that removing the nested `SingleConnectionFactory`s was another clue.