# Error initializing caching connectionfactory in tomcat 7.0

Tags: spring, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

i have found some similar tasks but none of them seems to fix my problem. I have a spring-application and deploy this application into a maven-jetty-plugin. All works fine... jetty comes up without errors, integrationtests are green. Next i wanted to get my app running in tomcat 7.0 but i get an exception and i'm not able to fix it. May be anybody has an idea. Thanks a lot in advance.

Please be aware, that it is my first app that i deploy into tomcat, so may be i did some very basic mistakes...

Here the exception:

```
2015-11-15 20:30:14,371 | ERROR | localhost-startStop-1 | o.s.w.c.ContextLoader | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-jms.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'targetConnectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'targetConnectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'targetConnectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'targetConnectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'targetConnectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Here is the spring-jms.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- START JMS Config -->

    <jms:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Possible productive configuration -->


    <amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false" >
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"> 
        <!-- all config for embedded url see http://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri.html -->
        <!-- <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://embedded?broker.persistent=false"/>-->
<!--        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"/> -->
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean> 



    <bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "destinationResolver" class = "org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver"></bean>

    <bean id="jmsListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="jmsErrorHandler"/>
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="destinationResolver"/>
        <property name="concurrency" value="1-10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "jmsErrorHandler" class = "com.mleitner.businessmaximizer.service.JMSErrorHandler" />

    <!-- END JMS Config -->

</beans>
```

Versions:

- activemq-all-5.12.0.jar
- spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- Tomcat 7.0

Update: pom.xml jetty-maven-plugin added:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.RC1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.179</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
                    </dependency> 
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
                        <version>5.7.0</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>       
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopWait>10</stopWait>
                    <jettyXml>${basedir}/jetty-config/jetty-env.xml</jettyXml>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log</name>
                            <value>org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/jetty-config/logback.xml</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <webApp>
                        <extraClasspath>${basedir}/jetty-config/</extraClasspath>
                    </webApp> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Update 2: I adapted jms-config (now i don't use any CachingConnectionFactory):

New jms-config:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"> 
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean> 
    <!--  
    <bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Nearly the same exception...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a classloader problem. I had two different jaxax.jms.ConnectionFactory versions in the classpath.

- javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar
- activemq-all-5.7.0.jar

Removing javax.jms-api solved the problem.

Comment: Saved me from hell :) Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

on the activeMQ documentation this is the way the use with Spring JMS

```
<!-- a pooling based JMS provider -->



 <bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop">
<property name="connectionFactory">
  <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL">
      <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
</property>


 </bean>

  <!-- Spring JMS Template -->
  <bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <ref local="jmsFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>`
```

Comment: I checked CachingConnectionFactory from spring: targetConnectionFactory is a javax.jms.ConnectionFactory and ActiveMQConnectionFactory implements javax.jms.ConnectionFactory => see http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.12.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html So all seems to be ok... and why it is working with jetty-maven-plugin?! Or did i understand your answer wrong?

Comment: May be there is some kind of jar-version conflict?! Could this be possible?

Comment: I still don't understand which java class you mean => there is no java class from me involved... this are all standard spring and activemq classes. I cannot change the attribute in spring CachingConnectionFactory from javax.jms.ConnectionFactory to ActiveMQConnectionFactory => to do this i have to build my own spring version...

Comment: Exclusion is a good hint... just one moment, i add my pom.xml for the jetty-maven-plugin => there i did an exclude.

Comment: also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165924/error-in-setexceptionlistener-in-sending-message-via-jmstemplate-to-activemq-as and this http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com.ar/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html

Comment: I adapted my initial post. And i think i do it excactly like in this bsnyderblog... i still don't understand why it doesn't work. Thank you for your efforts.